# OK button not working fine in Modal in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

Overview: As I click the trash-can for above list (check attached image), two modal dialog box appears (as there are two lists but only one should appear) and upon clicking on OK (to change the status of first list) the status of second is changed and the dialog box hides as the hide function is called. So in order to delete first list, initially I have to cross the first modal box and then I have to click OK to change the status of first list.

It seems like no matter which trash can I click the Modal box for latest list appears. e.g if there are ten lists, and I click trash-can of first list the Modal box of tenth list will appear and perform the action on it.

[image: the trash can needs to change status of corresponding list]

```
<template>
<b-container fluid="lg">
    <div style="height:20px"></div>
    <b-card>
      <section id="werkzeug" class ="col-12">
        <div class = "b-container">
          <h5 class = "section-title h1">Werkzeugbedarf löschen</h5>
        </div>
      </section>

  <div style="height:10px"></div>

  <b-form-group>

<div style="height:20px"></div>
    <b-row class="my-1">
      <b-col sm="3">
        <label>Transportbedarfnr.</label>
      </b-col>
      <b-col sm="9">
        <b-form-input
        type="number"
        class="form-control"
        :class="{'is-invalid': $v.form.TransportDemandsId.$error}"
        @blur="$v.form.TransportDemandsId.$touch()"
        v-model="form.TransportDemandsId"
        placeholder="Transportauftrag XYZ"></b-form-input>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.form.TransportDemandsId.numeric">Muss eine Nummer sein</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.form.TransportDemandsId.minLength">Muss min. {{$v.form.TransportDemandsId.$params.minLength.min}} Zahlen haben</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.form.TransportDemandsId.maxLength">Muss max. {{$v.form.TransportDemandsId.$params.maxLength.max}} Zahlen haben</div>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
</b-form-group>

    </b-card>
    <div style="height:15px"></div>

<b-row align-h="center">
<div>
  <b-button-toolbar key-nav>
    <b-button-group class="mx-2" size="lg">
      <b-button :to="{ name: 'Home' }" variant="light" class="border border-muted" ><strong class="text-muted">&laquo;  Zurück</strong></b-button>
    </b-button-group>

    <b-button-group class="mx-2" size="lg">
      <b-button
            @click="$bvModal.show('modal-1')"
            variant="light" class="border border-muted">
        <strong class="text-muted">Delete  &raquo;</strong></b-button>
      <b-modal id="modal-1" title="Please confirm">
        <p class="my-4">Are you sure you want to delete this?</p>
        <template v-slot:modal-footer="{ ok, cancel,}">
          
      <!-- Emulate built in modal footer ok and cancel button actions -->
      <b-button size="sm" variant="success" @click="okButtonClicked()" > OK </b-button>
      <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" @click="cancel()"> Cancel </b-button>
    </template>
      </b-modal>
    </b-button-group>

  </b-button-toolbar>
</div>
</b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { required, minLength, numeric, decimal, maxLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  name: 'DeleteForm',
  data () {
    return {
      form: { // validation der werte
        TransportDemandsId: '',
      },
    }
  },
  validations: { // validation der werte
    form: {
      TransportDemandsId: {
        minLength: minLength(1),
        maxLength: maxLength(6),
        numeric
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    okButtonClicked: async function() { 
      let td_id =this.form.TransportDemandsId;
      console.log(this.form.TransportDemandsId);
      let url = "https://localhost:44370/api/transportdemand/abort/" + td_id;
      const res = await axios.delete(url);      
      let data = res.data;
      
      if (data === true) {
        alert("Response: OK. Transport Demand is Deleted: " );
      } else {
        alert("Response: Transport Demand not found");
      };
      this.$bvModal.hide('modal-1');

        
      console.log("hide button");

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you bind `$bvModal` ?
It looks like you are calling the same method for both modals. so probably you are not making any difference between the modals. 
Can you add the entire code, with both modals?

Comment: there is only one modal .i.e. b-modal. please check the attached image, it may clear more what I am trying to say.

Comment: code is also updated

Comment: @CosminConstantinFirta binding is done by bootstrap-vue plugin https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal  "BootstrapVue will inject a $bvModal object into every Vue instance"

Comment: So the `DeleteForm` component is displayed for every row of the list?

Comment: @CosminConstantinFirta yes! unfortunately..

Comment: And you display them with a `v-for` statement?

Comment: no, with..$bvModal.show('modal name')

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it happens is fact that you have defined several `b-modal id="modal-1"`. When you have several `DeleteForm` components in list then as an output you will have several `b-modal id="modal-1"` as they are part of DeleteForm component. Then when you will run `$bvModal.show('modal-1')` then it will open modal for every modal defined with this id. To avoid such situation you will need to create new component for modal and you should not iterate by it. Second option is to create unique id for every modal inside the DeleteForm. You can for example pass some kind of id as a props. I hope that I described it good enough :)

Comment: Thanks Kadash! but I am already passing the unique id for list in URL.its given in method section at the end of code, am I passing it correctly?                                                       
let url = "https://localhost:44370/api/transportdemand/abort/" + td_id;

Comment: @KamranShakeel I meant unique id for every modal you have for example `<b-modal id="modal-1">` `<b-modal id="modal-2">` and then `$bvModal.show('modal-1')` `$bvModal.show('modal-2')` etc

Comment: ok, i got your point , but I am getting the entries from my sql database and the entries are being refresh after every minute dynamically and may reach up to 500 hundred at a time..so this solution might not work in my case I believe :(